# R and approximate match in the column's name

Tags: r

I notice that sometimes R uses approximate match when I manipulate a column.

Example

```
age=18:19
height=c(76.1,77)
village=data.frame(age=age,height=height)
village$test=village$ag+2
```

Instead of telling me that `village$ag` doesn't exist, it will use `village$age`.

Is it possible to change this behaviour ?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `[`

```
> village["ag"]
Fehler in `[.data.frame`(village, "ag") : undefined columns selected

> village["age"]
  age
1  18
2  19
```

The function `[[` allows both approaches (argument `exact`):

```
> village[["ag"]]
NULL

> village[["age"]]
[1] 18 19

> village[["ag", exact = FALSE]]
[1] 18 19
```

The phenomenon is called *partial matching* (see `?pmatch`):

```
> pmatch("ag", names(village))
[1] 1
```

Comment: Is it just possible to desactivate this partial matching ?